# How can I relaunch juju daemons without stop/starting local LXC containers?

Tags: juju, lxc

I'm using juju in local mode with LXC.

I updated `juju` on the host with a classical:

```
apt-get install juju
```

And had a plentyful of python errors in `juju debug-log` probably because juju processes weren't restarted.

In order to restart juju processes, I had to do a complete:

```
juju destroy-environment
juju bootstrap
```

which deleted all contents in `/var/lib/lxc`. I was warned, and this was not an issue, but will be when I'll be in a production environment.

Is there a way to relaunch juju daemons without stop/starting LXC local VMs ?

Comment: You don't need to restart the juju daemons (jujud) running on machines in your environment if you upgrade your juju client on your machine. If on the other hand want to upgrade jujud version inside the environment, you'll need to run `juju upgrade-juju`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround might be to restart the machine, but I don't think it works at this time:

"Local provider environments do not survive reboots of the host at this time, the environment will need to be destroyed and recreated after a reboot." from

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-local.html

See also bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/juju/+bug/955576