# Ubuntu Juju local configure failed

Tags: juju, configure

When i run bootstrap in [How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage) i got this error. I have done the same steps. So why that error is comming? Then i checked the permission for index.json file i changed permission but it didn't work.

```
ERROR failed getting all instances: error executing "lxc-ls": Traceback (most recent call last):;   File "/usr/bin/lxc-ls", line 31, in <module>;     import lxc;   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxc/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>;     import _lxc; ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxc.so.1: undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync
ERROR error executing "lxc-ls": Traceback (most recent call last):;   File "/usr/bin/lxc-ls", line 31, in <module>;     import lxc;   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxc/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>;     import _lxc; ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxc.so.1: undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync
ERROR Bootstrap failed, and the environment could not be destroyed: exit status 1
ERROR rename /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/.tmp/juju-filestorage-670557739 /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/tools/streams/v1/index.json: permission denied
```

These are the steps I followed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core
sudo apt-get install juju-local
ssh-keygen -t rsa
juju init
juju switch local
juju bootstrap

ERROR error executing "lxc-ls": Traceback (most recent call last):; File "/usr/bin/lxc-ls", line 31, in <module>; import lxc; File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxc/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>; import _lxc; ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxc.so.1: undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having exactly the same problem on a clean install I did of trusty this morning. I had to do an upgrade. I was getting the *undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync* error when running lxc-ls as well.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Read more about bootstrapping:
[**>** Configuring for LXC](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-LXC.html)
[**>** Bootstrapping and Destroying](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-LXC.html#bootstrapping-and-destroying)

Some cite:

> The usage of LXC Linux Containers requires root privileges for some
>   steps. Juju will prompt for your password if needed. Juju cannot be
>   run under sudo because it needs to manage permission as the real user.

Other way to solve problem:

1. Try:

   ```
   sudo rm ~/.juju/environments/local.jenv
   ```

   and then reconfigure or reinstall from PPA's steps or SSH key generation.
2. To remove all current deployments and clear up everything in your cloud, you can run the command:

   ```
   juju destroy-environment  <environment-name>
   ```

   Where the `<environment-name>` is the name you gave the environment when you configured it. This extra details is to help prevent accidents! You will also see a warning and will be prompted whether or not to continue - this action will remove everything, including the bootstrap node. **Warning!**
3. Also with **WARNING!** this command will destroy the "local" environment (type: local)
   This includes all machines, services, data and other resources.

   ```
   juju destroy-environment local --force
   ```
4. And again with **WARNING!**
   To log your LXC destroy (to view LXC trouble and post your log):

   ```
   juju destroy-environment local --logging-config=golxc=TRACE;juju=DEBUG --show-log
   ```

Comment: Thanks your response.I am new to juju and LXC. So i have done same steps which are in your links.So still didn,t work.When i create yaml file it did't have any admin secret value.

Comment: you use 12.04 or newer?

Comment: I am using ubuntu server 14.04 is that trouble ??

Comment: No, sorry. I think your **ufw** halted your bootstraping. Maybe you need add local storage port rules to your **ufw** config

Comment: you mean i want to disable firewall.

Comment: yes, or disable.

Comment: I have disabled but it didn't work.Before that is that need to start LXC server ?? i only followed the steps in this one.http://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage it didn't mention about LXC server.

Comment: This is the error i got WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/sajith/.juju/environments/local.jenv"
uploading tools for series [trusty precise]
ERROR rename /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/.tmp/juju-filestorage-398578572 /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/tools/streams/v1/index.json: permission denied

Comment: just try: `sudo rm ~/.juju/environments/local.jenv` and then reconfigure or reinstall from PPA's steps or ssh key generation. I think no other way due to it is more lightly problem for our tender Juju ))

Comment: First i remove local.jnev file and then try to gen key pair and after that i try to bootstrap again.But now it gives another error.

Comment: Just post here the code I will add to your question if you cannot edit.

Comment: ERROR error executing "lxc-ls": Traceback (most recent call last):;   File "/usr/bin/lxc-ls", line 31, in <module>;     import lxc;   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxc/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>;     import _lxc; ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxc.so.1: undefined symbol: cgmanager_get_pid_cgroup_abs_sync

Comment: These are the steps i followed :-                             sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core
sudo apt-get install juju-local
ssh-keygen -t rsa
juju init
juju switch local
juju bootstrap

Comment: read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218593/how-can-i-relaunch-juju-daemons-without-stop-starting-local-lxc-containers?rq=1

Comment: update: added command to log your LXC destroy.

Comment: Hi Still i got this error   :-   ERROR rename /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/.tmp/juju-filestorage-754545545 /home/sajith/.juju/local/storage/tools/streams/v1/index.json: permission denied

Comment: your problem is lxc, read answer by Jorge: http://askubuntu.com/a/403619/38988

Comment: it didn't work.I remove all the stuffs and still same result.

Comment: I get exactly the same error. I get the same error by just running lxc-ls